# Is there a way to automatically join many tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-queries

I just imported ~50 tables; each table has 2 common foreign keys (making each record unique).  My goal is to setup a query that joins all these tables; I obviously don't want to have to this manually and was thinking about setting up a procedure that loops through all tables to dynamically build this query ... is this the best way or is there an obvious solution I'm not seeing?  Thanks you

Comment: you can query `information_schema.tables` to get the tables. if it's a one time thing I would probably go with that.

Comment: Yeah. that's what I ended up doing ... looping through those tables and building my query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** there is not. You have to manually write the query to JOIN the tables.

You can also check [Automatically Generate a Set of Join Filters Between Merge Articles (SQL Server Management Studio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms151739.aspx) but I am not sure if that is going to help.